# Как определить "компиляторный" тип объекта?

Tags: java, generics, рефлексия

```
public class GenericMethods {
    public <A,B,C> void f(A x,B y, C z) {
        System.out.println(x.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(y.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(Класс.вывести_то_что_видит_компилятор(y));
        System.out.println(z.getClass().getName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericMethods gm = new GenericMethods();
        gm.<String,Object,GenericMethods>f("Hello", 54, gm);
    }
}
```

***Вопрос:***
Можно ли как то заставить JVM показать тот тип переменной `y` внутри функции `f()`, который формально она имеет на стадии компиляции? Если RTTI использовать, то мы увидим `java.lang.Integer`, но я насильно указал в дженериках брать `java.lang.Object` для параметризованного типа `B` к которому и относится переменная `y`. Т. е. я не хочу видеть *реальный* тип `y`. Мне нужно узнать формальный...

Comment: [Type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure) = "стирание типов". Это про то что, все проверки на дженериках производятся в момент компиляции., а в рантайме внутри дженериков типов нет.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Очень полезная информация. Был бы ещё более признателен за ссылку на какой либо хороший источник, где про это пишут!

Comment: Есть небольшая книга (200+ страниц) [*Java Generics and Collections:  Speed Up the Java Development Process / by Naftalin & Wadler*](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0596527756/). Думаю, она многое прояснит.

Comment: PS. В Java *RTTI* называется *Reflection*.

Comment: Pss. Я считал, что работая с классом Class мы работаем с RTTI, как только мы включаемся в классы Method, Annotation, Field, Constructor (etc), мы говорим об Отражении... Это формально, но книга "Thinking in Java" более грамотно объясняет это. RTTI и есть RTTI пока мы спрашиваем у .class файлов конкретный тип, который был известен при компиляции. А если наши классы где-то на другом конце света (на удалённом севере), то мы уже работаем с отражениями. Вот как-то так вроде...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Нельзя.**

Формальные параметры существуют только на стадии компиляции. Компилятор [стирает](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) информацию о них. Типы, доступные на стадии исполнения называются reifiable (материализуемые?, не уверен в переводе).

Критерии типов, доступных во время исполнения описаны в спецификации Java, параметры обобщенных типов недоступны:

> [4.7. Reifiable Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7)
>   Because some type information is erased during compilation, not all types are available at run time. Types that are completely available at run time are known as reifiable types.
>   A type is reifiable if and only if one of the following holds:
>    - It refers to a non-generic class or interface type declaration.
>    - It is a parameterized type in which all type arguments are unbounded
>      wildcards (§4.5.1).
>    - It is a raw type (§4.8).
>    - It is a primitive type (§4.2).
>    - It is an array type (§10.1) whose element type is reifiable.
>    - It is a nested type where, for each type T separated by a ".", T itself is reifiable.
>   ...
>   *4.7. Материализуемые типы
>
>   Т.к. часть информации стирается при компиляции, не все типы доступны во время исполнения. Доступны во время исполнения типы, для которых выполняется одно из следующих условий:
>
>    - Тип является непараметризованным классом или интерфейсом.
>
>    - Параметризованный тип, в котором все аргументы типа являются неограниченными символами подстановки.
>
>    - Несформированные типы.
>
>    - Примитивные типы.
>
>    - Массивы, тип элемента которого доступен во время выполнения.
>
>    - Вложенные типы, где для всех типов `T`, разделенных точкой тип `T` является доступным во время выполнения.*

Остальные типы затираются

**Если ОЧЕНЬ хочется:**

Если в качестве эксперимента нужно сохранить информацию о типе, то можно сделать это для параметров классов. Заставить компилятор сохранять информацию о указанных типах можно, создавая для каждого типа параметра анонимный класс. Например, если создать класс:

```
abstract class GenericClass<T> {
    private final T value;
    public GenericClass(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }  

    /**
    * Пытается отловить значение типа, которое использовалось при компиляции.
    * Сработает только для параметризованных наследников
    */
    public Type getCompileTimeType() {
        final Type superclass = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        if(!(superclass instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("С непараметризованными не получится");
        }
        final Type[] types = ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments();
        return types[0];
    }

    public Type getActualType() {
        return value.getClass();
    }
}
```

И создать объект анонимного класса, который от него унаследован:

```
//анонимный класс, обратите внимание на {}
GenericClass clazz = new GenericClass<Object>(5) {}
```

, то метод `getCompileTimeType` вернет `Object`, а `getActualType` — `Integer`.

Это происходит за счет того, что компилятор создает для анонимного класса отдельного наследника `GenericClass` равносильного следующему классу:

```
class ObjectClass extends GenericClass<Object>{
    public ObjectClass(Object value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

, что позволяет сохранить для рефлексии тип параметра `GenericClass`. При этом нужно иметь ввиду, что компилятор будет создавать отдельные классы для каждого типа параметра (`GenericClass<Integer>`, `GenericClass<Object>` и т.д.), что может отрицательно сказаться на производительности.

Этот механизм подойдет для экспериментов и изучения работы компилятора и обобщенных типов. Использовать его на практике не стоит, т.к. механизм крайне неочевиден, неэффективен и хрупок.

**Ссылки:**

- Вопрос по затиранию типов в английской версии: [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)
- Статья про извлечение типов параметров из анонимных классов: [Using TypeTokens to retrieve generic parameters](https://rgomes-info.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/using-typetokens-to-retrieve-generic.html)

Comment: Как вытащить параметризованный тип из класса, я понял с Вашей помощью! Но есть ли какой нибудь танец с бубнами, который поможет вытащить Тип-Параметр из (всё-таки!) метода? Или это однозначно невозможно?

Comment: @Direct насколько я понимаю тему такого танца нет. Для того чтобы тип-параметр имел шансы пережить затирание он должен быть *явно* задан хотя бы в одном классе. Единственный вариант это всегда обращаться к методу через класс и передавать объект класса в метод для отлова типа, но это эквивалентно переносу метода в класс.

Comment: Да, понял. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

> Мне нужно узнать формальный

Type erasure не даст вам его узнать. Для рантайма там везде будет `Object`.